# unable to generate a keystore from an existing certificate file

Tags: android-keystore

I've lost my keystore file that was used to make release build for an android app. But I've the certificate file. Now I want to generate a new keystore from this existing certificate file but I'm unable to do that because I've forgot the alias name that was set when the keystore was created for the first time. Is there a way that I can use the same certificate file and generate a new keystore ? I have tried the following command but it didn't work.

```
keytool -import -alias foo -file certfile.cer -keystore publicKey.store
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Generating_a_Private_Key_and_a_Keystore) link help ?

Generate a keystore using following command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks
```

Import CER file in java keystore:

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```